# Add backwards compatibility after release

Tags: android, google-play, updates, android-version

Let's say I publish an app to the Google Play store with the minimum SDK set to Jelly Bean MR2 (API 18). Later, I realize that I want to be supporting back to Ice Cream Sandwich (15).

Does Google Play allow updates to be pushed that change the minimum SDK? Can I simply change the min SDK from 18 to 15 and (assuming everything works correctly) push an update?

EDIT: I have re-written the question to show a more viable use-case

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend it, but (using your example version #s) I believe you can change the minimum version of your 1.1 APK to KitKat. This update would only work for them, although JellyBean users may get a warning. When you release 1.2 you could then change back the minimum version to whatever it used to be.